# cant save as .blender

Tags: mesh

[image]

I am A Sims4 user and I've been trying to create new hairstyle.
But I seem to be unable to save as .blender so i cant open it on blender
[image]

Do i have to download something else to be able to save as .blender?
I'm confused help please

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specifically about Blender

Comment: In this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdPEPRm9s9Y) it shows a mesh direct export option to blender available, so I think what you wish to export is not possible... (it seems a picture, maybe a picture of the hair?). I've never user TS4, though.

Answer (score 1):

The file type is .blend, but it is not a format you can just save to like an image file format. You will need to look for an exporter to go to maybe .obj file format or something like it that handles mesh and materials together.